# Unable to redirect to other url in apache

Tags: linux, apache, proxy

I have two Redhat Linux servers, say 'original' and 'demo'. Both have apache running on them. On original server, I have a link 'http://original.com/abc' on a page which I want redirect it to http://demo.com.

What I have done is-

Open httpd.conf on original server and added following lines and restarted apache service:

```
ProxyPass         /abc  http://demo.com/
ProxyPassReverse  /abc  http://demo.com/
```

But when I am trying to access http://original.com/abc, it is redirecting me to the original server i.e. on http://original.com (not on http://demo.com)

I have tried to find the solutions on various sites but unable to find out what the problem is.

Edit: 
Output of `curl -v http://original.com/abc`:

```html
curl -v http://original.com/abc
* About to connect() to original.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.100.100.100...
* Connected to original.com (10.100.100.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /demo HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: original.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 06:30:23 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Location: login.action
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0BAA246C7F2505D2F5A0335CB0542CAA; Path=/; HttpOnly
<
* Connection #0 to host original.com left intact
```

Output of `curl -v http://demo.com/` :

```html
#curl -v http://demo.com
* About to connect() to 10.100.100.101 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.100.100.101...
* Connected to 10.100.100.101 (10.100.100.101) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: demo.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FED19458459131F456D638EC57278C2A; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: login.action
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 06:31:47 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host demo.com left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

The textual order of ProxyPass statements is relevant. The first matched entry stops further matching.

```
ProxyPass         /     http://some.tomcat:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /     http://some.tomcat:8080/
...
ProxyPass         /abc  http://demo.com/
ProxyPassReverse  /abc  http://demo.com/
```

Here, demo.com would be fed nothing. The some.tomcat would be fed both `/` and `/abc`

Comment: One interesting thing is that I have written ProxyPass statement above the some.tomcat:8080 line then I am getting redirect to the same server as I said earlier. But when I am putting ProxyPass statement for demo below the some.tomcat:8080 line then I am getting 403 error (HTTP Access to the requested resource has been denied) error message.